# Inksacpe: Is it possible to add relative links for multipage navigation

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, inkscape, multipage

I try to create a multipage pdf with navigation from one page to the other using Inkscape 1.2.
Therefore I created an object A on Page 1 and an object B on Page 2. Object B has the id `myId`.

It is possible to add a link to object A with the Id `myId` in Inkscape by defining `href="#myId"` in the link-properties. The link in the resulting svg-file work at least if object B sits on page 1 (as normal browsers do not display two pages from the inkscape-svg).

However it **does not work** in the **PDF-File**, saved from Inkscape. The Link seems to point to a path `{directory}file:\#myId` where `{directory}` is the directory-path of the PDF-file, that also changes when the pdf-file is moved to another path. Maybe this is a bug in Inkscape and `file:\` would have to be replaced by the actual current filename. Then the link would make sense again.

I found the project [svgLinkify](https://github.com/oxplot/svglinkify) on github. But they say it is depreciated as inkscape enabled this functionality in version 1.2.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can directly ask Inkscape developers here: https://chat.inkscape.org/channel/team_devel